# Knowage BI Oracle DataSource

Tags: oracle, fiware-knowage

I have a question about knowage (open-source BI software - www.knowage-suite.com)

Can anyone tell me how create DataSource with add Oracle data source?

Regards, Pokil

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedure of setting up the DataSource is well documented and publicly available on their website. You can find it here:

https://knowage-suite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/administrator-guide/configure-data-sources.html#connect-to-your-data

For Oracle you should use JDBC. The parameters have to be something like this:

- Dialect: `Oracle`
- Url: JDBC connection string, something like `jdbc:oracle://servername:port/sid`
- Driver: `com.oracle.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: I follow the settings, but I still can't get online

Error message  "Connection Test failed, please look for more details in log file and check Your parameters"

My database version: Oracle 11G (11.2.0.3)
Ask me how to troubleshoot the error

Comment: You should check the log file for any hints. If the logfile contains some ORA-xxxxx errors, you are on a good way to solve the issue.

Comment: View log, no ora-xxx related information, only error log: [http-bio-8080-exec-4] 250 months 2018 11:16:15,203 ERROR
It.eng.spagobi.tools.datasource.service.rest.testconnection.testdatasourcenew:200-error Testing DataSources Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.oracle.jdbc.Driver, do you have an error setting?

Comment: This post is old, but you must copy oracle jdbc jar driver to tomcat/lib directory.